# Android Volley Synchronize Server SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-volley

I am new to android development, just started with sqlite.

Working on location app that should retrieve locations from mongo server, and populate local SQLite db.
Listview, Search queries etc.. should use local db data.

I am using volley library for my networking.

Questions:

1- After getting volley response, how do i populate sqlite?

2- How do I send updated location data from server to device?
    (I dont need to update server with device info.)

3- How do i ensure sqlite only gets updated, not overwriten from server everytime?

I have seen examples using asynctask, syncadapter etc... But at this 
point in project i cannot change my code from volley.

My volley code below (currently parses json to object):

```
    private void getResource() {
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jObjR = new JsonArrayRequest(url_all_points, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            parseJSON(response);

        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {           
            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
       }
    }
);

rq.add(jObjR);
}

private void parseJSON(JSONArray response) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject coord = jsonObj.getJSONObject("coord");
                MyLocation wj = new MyLocation();
                wj.setTitle(jsonObj.optString("name"));
                wj.setLat(coord.optDouble("latitude"));
                wj.setLng(coord.optDouble("longitude"));
                mLocations.add(wj);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(wj.getmLat(), wj.getmLng());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                      .title(wj.getTitle()));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```